# Why a groupby dataframe becomes a series, after applying the quantile function to it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe, and if I apply a groupby to it, and then a quantile, it gets converted to a series:

```
gp = gp_[['Power_kw', 'bins']].groupby('bins')

power_med = gp.quantile(0.5)

type(power_med)

pandas.core.series.Series
```

But if I run the same code, with the same python version (3.7) on a Mac, the `power_med` data type is still a dataframe, and not a series.

Tried `to_frame()`, but it messes up the data.

Can you please help?

Comment: Are you running both under the same version of Pandas?

Comment: Good spot... just checked it was due to a different pandas version. Many thanks!